# Node Socket_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT

Tags: node.js, multer, cloudinary, nodejs-server, multer-gridfs-storage

I am trying to upload a disk file via cloudinary in my JS file. im using multer as middleware and my
**uploadonCloudinary** function

```js
const uploadOnCloudinary = async (localFilePath) => {
    try {
        if (!localFilePath) return null
        //upload the file on cloudinary
        const response = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(localFilePath,{
            resource_type: "auto"
        })
        //file has been uploaded successfull
        console.log("file is uploaded on cloudinary ", response.url);
        fs.unlinkSync(localFilePath)
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("error uploading",error);
        fs.unlinkSync(localFilePath) // remove the locally saved temporary file as the upload operation got failed
        return null;
    }
}

# *gives me an error:

error uploading {
  error: Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1099:20)
      at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1638:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
    code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
  }
}
*
```

How to fix this been stuck since a long Time used different Stable Node versions

if any specific node version would help do share it and if any other method to resolve this error

Comment: A few clarification questions:
What version of Node are you running, and what version of the Cloudinary SDK? Can you ping api.cloudinary.com from the machine running the code? Do simple uploads without Multer work?

Comment: The file has to be uploaded from client side to the server side through Multer, and then the file can be uploaded to Cloudinary using the SDK (at server side). Also, may I recommend referring to some guidelines as [described in this document](https://dev.to/arifulhasantotul/single-and-multiple-images-upload-and-remove-from-cloudinary-using-node-js-multer-mongodb-1p2h) and from [this link as well](https://www.codementor.io/@joejackson045/uploading-images-to-cloudinary-using-multer-and-expressjs-zthuy53oi).